# How this Fold Tree Function works in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tree, fold

Here i am trying to understand this function which folds a tree to one value. It shows that foldTree takes two functions as arguments, it applies first function to the element of the `Tree a` and then passes the result to second function `(b->b->b)` which again performs some operation and produces final result.

```
foldTree :: (a -> b) -> (b -> b -> b) -> Tree a -> b
foldTree f g (Leaf x) = f x
foldTree f g (Node tl tr) = g (foldTree f g tl) (foldTree f g tr)
```

I am trying following input to see how it works.

```
Input 1:  foldTree (*2) (\x y -> x + y) (Leaf 6)
Input 2:  foldTree (*2) (\x y -> x + y) (Node (Node (Leaf 1) (Leaf 2)) (Leaf 4))
```

It returns

```
Output 1 : 12
Output 2 : 14
```

The problem i am facing in understanding is where the second function argument operation is performed? and how it actually passes the values to the second function, apparently second function takes two values as arguments but first function only returns one value... from where the second value is passed? Can i say it took result of first function *twice* so that `x` and `y` values are same? because second function `(\x y -> x + y)` takes *two* arguments? but then result would not be same as mentioned in output 1 and 2.

Secondly does it return the final result after performing second function or it returns the result after applying only the first function because i am confused even i removed second function it produces the same results.

Thirdly what is the purpose of `g` here outside of two curly brackets? `***g*** (foldTree f g tl) (foldTree f g tr)` it took it as a Data constructor from the start or what? I know data constructor can be constructed as smart constructors but here how it treated.

I am so confused understanding this, may be i am complicating a lot of concepts in this one? Please don't hesitate to go into details.

Comment: `foldTree f g tree` basically applies `f` to each leaf of the tree, then recursively applies `g` between the components of each `Node`, so e.g. `foldTree f g (Node (Node (Leaf 1) (Leaf 2)) (Leaf 4)) = g (g (f 1) (f 2)) (f 4)`.

Comment: ... or IOW, ``(f 1 `g` f 2) `g` f 4`` == `((*2) 1 + (*2) 2) + (*2) 4` == `(1*2 + 2*2) + 4*2`.

Comment: @bradrn Thanks, I understand what you said, but i am confused how it interpreted to apply g to the components of Node. And what would be the definition of g in this case? How it interpreted (b->b->b) function whereas to me it just seems, same as function (a->b).  Apologies, i am beginner in this.

Comment: @bradrn how it mapped (\x y -> x + y) to (b->b->b) what is x and y after first function passed the output to (\x y -> x + y)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand the result of `foldTree f g tree` you can use this technique:

- Write down the value of `tree` using the constructors, e.g. in your example we have `(Node (Node (Leaf 1) (Leaf 2)) (Leaf 4))`.
- Syntactically replace `Leaf` with `f` and `Node` with `g`. For the previous example, we get `(g (g (f 1) (f 2)) (f 4))`.
- Use the definitions of functions `f` and `g` to compute the result of the last expression. For the example, we get `((+) ((+) ((*2) 1) ((*2) 2)) ((*2) 4))` which is
  `((+) ((+) (1*2) (2*2)) (4*2))` which is `((1*2) + (2*2)) + (4*2)` which is `(2+4)+8 = 14`.

Note how we replace `Leaf` a unary constructor with `f`, a unary function, and `Node`, a binary constructor with `g`, a binary function. So, we always have the right number of arguments for our functions. More in general, the types will match just fine.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. It treated g as a binary data constructor? Why we replaced g with the Node? Whereas Node is a part of Tree where as (b->b->b) is a separate binary function?

Comment: @Sniper `g` indeed plays the role of the binary constructor `Node`, when folding. We replace `Node` with `g` since that's how `foldTree` is defined: `foldTree f g (Node .. ..) = g (..) (..)`, so a `Node` becomes `g` when expanding the definition. Essentially, `Node` is a binary constructor function function taking two `Tree`s, while `g` generalizes that to take any two `b`s. Similarly, `Leaf ...` becomes `f ..` when expanding the definition.